# Toggle edit mode in another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, edit

I have a ViewController (with a container view) embedded in a Navigation controller. The container contains a pageViewController with one of the 'pages' being a TableViewController (with UITableView outlet: 'aTableView'). I want to trigger the edit mode in the tableViewController when tapping a custom editButton in the navigation bar. When I create a custom editutton in the tableViewController the edit mode works as expected, but when I use the custom editButton in the navigation bar the setEditing bool value remains zero even when I setEditing to YES in the editButton selector. Here's the code:

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.editBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.editBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 22)];
    [self.editBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goToToggleEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:self.editBtn];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;

}

-(void)goToToggleEdit:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    TableViewController *tvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aTableViewController"];
    if(something==foo){
        [tvc toggleEdit];
     }
}
```

**aTableViewController.h**

```
@interface aTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *aTableView;

}

-(void) toggleEdit ;

@end
```

**aTableViewController.m**

```
-(void)toggleEdit {
    [aTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    NSLog(aTableView.editing ? @"Yes" : @"No");  // --> logss 'No'.
    if (aTableView.editing){
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something else 
    }
}
```

How can I efficiently trigger the edit mode in the tableViewController this way?

**Edit**
@Bagrat Kirakosian pointed out to me that my view hierarchy (Navigation Controller > View Controller (with containter) > Page View Controller (in container) > Table View Controller) might be the problem. I just want to create a Navigation Bar (with an edit button) that is fixed, therefore I can't embed the Table View Controller directly in a Navigation Controller.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE: Solution**

I have accepted @sebastien's solution although both @sebastien's and @Bagrat's solution work great. @Bagrat's answer includes direct access to the Table View Controllers, while @sebastien's solution calls edit mode in the pageViewController. I think, considering the tricky hierarchy, the latter is a bit more secure.

Comment: You should provide more of your code, especially, we need to see how you are implementing your `UITableView` and your `editButton`

Comment: Check edit. I updated some of the example code.

Comment: Try changing `if(something==foo)` with `if(true)`

Comment: Already tried that, no succes. Check the aTableViewController.m, the log = NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your issue here is that you are trying to access an embedded controller in a wrong way.

You are actually managing 2 differents `PageViewController`:

- The one you generated through your storyboard
- The other one you are initiating in your code further

That's why you can't reach the expected result.

First of all, add a new method to your `PageViewController`:

PageViewController.h:

```
- (void)editTableAtIndex:(int)index;
```

PageViewController.m:

```
- (void)editTableAtIndex:(int)index {
    [[self viewControllerAtIndex:index] setEditing:YES];
}
```

Now, in your main ViewController, access the `PageViewController` by using `childViewControllers`:

```
-(void)toggleEdit:(id)sender
{
    PageViewController *pvc = self.childViewControllers[0];
    [pvc editTableAtIndex:0];
}
```

It should be editing your `TodoListTableView`:

[image]

(Please notice that I used `[pvc editTableAtIndex:0];`, instead you should be calling something like `[pvc editTableAtIndex:_PageViewController_current_index_];`)

Comment: Still doesn't work. And the aTableView.editing log is still no?

Comment: Can you provide your sources, I'll be checking them and give you back some advises ASAP

Comment: https://github.com/sennevanbaelen/ToDoApp. Since I just started learning ObjC/cocoa three weeks ago I have to warn you the code looks very messy. I was just experimenting with some functions and the cocoa API.

Comment: @Baekel, I edited the answer according to your sources.

Comment: You are very welcome, do not forget about `[pvc editTableAtIndex:_PageViewController_current_index_]`

Comment: Well I agree, this can work but you never do isKindOfClass checks which is totally not secure. What if view controller first child changes somehow? Also you never got an access to table view. You just have one method for to manipulate things

Comment: @Bagrat Considering the tricky View Hierarchy I think it is just a bit more safe to trigger the edit mode from the pageViewController. I can still call a tableViewController method in my pageViewController and implement security checks myself. Although both solutions seem to work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for my View Controller that totally work fine. be sure you configure your bar button in the right method of View Controller lifecycle. Also be sure that your @selector is properly implemented in your code.

**In the same View Controller put these two blocks of code**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_icon.png" ] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(edit:)];
    [rightBarButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  rightBarButton;
}
```

Afterwards you need also to put your edit selector

```
-(void)edit:(UIButton *)sender {
    // Toggle edit by inverting current edit state
    // Also in this block change your right bar button text or image
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

After your comment we got to whole another question. You problem is not in the part where you try to call toggle edit. Your problem is the wrong hierarchy of controllers **(Navigation Controller > View Controller > Page View Controller > Table View Controller)**. This might cause a problem. Try to change your controllers like this;

```
UINavigationController > UIPageViewController > UIViewController(s)
```

Also it's a good practice to have a `UITableView` in `UIViewController` rather than using really dead `UITableViewController`. Don't forget to connect your tableView IBOutlet (by the way you didn't need it in UITableViewController), also connect `datasource` and `delegate` to Files owner. In your MyTableViewVC.h file add this line

```
@interface MyTableViewVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

After that all your calls will work fine.

---

**UPDATE 2**

After analyzing your entire structure I found a mistake that you do every time on the button click.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
tvc = [[TodolistTableViewController alloc] init];
```

When you call storyboard every time it's ok but when you do `[[TodolistTableViewController alloc] init]` you are **RE-MAKING** the same table view controller every time but not even adding it to your main view. As I told you, your tricky hierarchy might cause difficulties but it has a solution.

In your `PageViewController.m` make **tv1** and **tv2** properties in .h file, like so.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableViewController *tv1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableViewController *tv2;
```

Then in the view controller file do this

```
-(void)toggleEdit:(id)sender
{


    PageViewController *current = (PageViewController *)[[self childViewControllers] firstObject];

    if ([current isKindOfClass:[PageViewController class]])
    {
        [((TodolistTableViewController *)[current tv1]) toggleEdit];
    }

}
```

Answer includes all security checks and direct access to your table view controllers, because you might need to change other properties/call functions later.

Now in `-(void)toggleEdit:(id)sender` you don't re-create your views every time but you catch the ones you already have in your current View Controller.

Good Luck!

Comment: That's basically how I implemented it. I edited my post provide more code.

Comment: @Baekel can you explain me your correct hierarchy? You cant have something like this (Navigation Controller > View Controller > Page View Controller  > Table View Controller). Explain more what you did there?

Comment: That might be the problem then. My hierarchy is like that: Navigation Controller > View Controller (with container) > Page View Controller (in Container) > Table View Controller. I first embedded the TableViewController in a Navigation Controller but then the Nav Con is part of the page and I wanted it fixed...

Comment: @Baekel please check out UPDATE 1 and please provide your source files.

Comment: Check edit. I added the source code. Note this is still with the wrong View hierarchy. I will try your updated solution now.

Comment: @Baekel Check update 2, implement that in your code and it will work totally fine :)

Comment: Somehow logging e.g. "(TodolistTableViewController *)[current tv1] " in ViewController returns Null and the toggleEdit method does not get called? What am I missing? For double checking I even copied your solution code?

Comment: check if you added tv1 and tv2 as properties in PageViewController.h and @synthesize them in PageViewController.m also check viewDidLoad from redefining tv1 and tv2

Comment: @Baekel if you are not convinced with the quality of this answer check out this link with your same source code with updated files https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j33o0dibqqg7eia/AABblJ68owHblR_amUckrkeJa?dl=0

Comment: I am convinced with the solution. Works perfectly fine. I just forgot to synthesize or use _tv1. My mistake, guess I needed some sleep first ;). Up you go.